# Saving one sheet as PDF in Google Drive (for all Users)

Tags: google-sheets-macros

I made an Excel Sheet in Google Drive to be used by 15 Peoples. The function is that the macro should create a PDF from the Sheet and send it to peoples as Mail. But I want to make a copy as PDF in Google Drive where can I see all of this persons permissions to see all of the sent Mails.

I must say that I am a beginner for this macro thing, I tried 2 codes but I always get the same Error.

```
function TEST2() 
{
  var Datum = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm");
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var newas = SpreadsheetApp.create("XX");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("XX");
  sheet = as.getSheetByName("XX");
  sheet.copyTo(newas);

  newas.getSheetByName('XX');
  newas.deleteActiveSheet();

  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newas.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var anhang = {fileName:("XX Order" + Datum + ".pdf"),content:pdf,mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  var folderID = "TEST FOLDER";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(folder);

  newFile;

  MailApp.sendEmail(
    {
      to: "Mail Adress",
      subject: "XX Order " + Datum,
      htmlBody: "XX - Order ",
      attachments: anhang
    })

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Mail wurde versendet ' + Datum)

  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

I always get the same Error message. That the script cannot find a document with this ID.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution :)

```
  var folderID = "XXX BESTELLUNG";
  var folderID2 = "XXX Bestellung";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderID);
  var theblob = newas.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName('XXX Bestellung ' + Datum);
  var newFile = folder.next().getFoldersByName(folderID2).next().createFile(theblob);
```

when i change the code in this case, i get the solution whicht i want :)